# How many questions is too many?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a [single user posting a lot of Docker-related questions](https://devops.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11179) in the past few days. Is this behavior acceptable or is it considering flooding? If that's the case, I could manage to convince him to calm down.

Comment: http://mentalfloss.com/article/27322/11-famous-illeists

Comment: @chicks Or maybe he was just schizophrenic :D

Answer (score 4):

I hope most people are focused on quality and not quantity.  Since the majority of your questions have at least one up-vote it seems like you're falling on the good side of things.  You might want to look back at the ones that didn't get up votes to see if they could be turned into better questions, but maybe they were just overlooked because we don't have enough docker folks lurking here.

I don't recall seeing any complaints about question volume on any of the StackExchange sites that I've been on.  I got fussed at once for submitting too many suggested edits so I try to keep those to a few per day per site.  This makes sense because there's a limited about of time people have to review these things and it is all effort being put in by volunteers in their "spare" time.